# asp.net MVC calling wcf service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have asp.net application which i am planning to convert into asp.net mvc app.

One area that i havn't found how it could be done is, App is using scriptmanager to make ajax calls to wcf service. And scriptmanager simply takes care or all element related to ajax, serializing - etc.

I haven't found what i can use in mvc that replaces that piece of functionality

- Server hosting WCF service
- MVC calling wcf service through ajax?
- No controller, view etc to wrap wcf service to respond for ajax call

I found lot about using jquery, ajaxaction stuff but this don't look like exact replacement of scriptmanager like functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, the easiest method would be to continue to use the ScriptManager control in the MVC port of the application.

The [Polymorphic Podcast](http://polymorphicpodcast.com/) did a [show](http://polymorphicpodcast.com/shows/mvcajax/) on this topic. There are several potentially helpful links in the [show notes](http://polymorphicpodcast.com/shows/mvcajax/).